# How can I edit the magnifier zooming factor?

Tags: desktop, accessibility

I am trying to control the zoom in & out factor, searched using `dconf editor` for the factor and found one:
[image: dconf window]

But changing `2` to any other number doesn't change the magnifier factor. Is there any solutions?